# Как в скрипте отключить коллайдер у объекта

Tags: unity3d

Я создаю игру с монетками и когда игрок задевает монетку проигрывается анимация и монетка пропадает и прибавляется числу собранных монет. Мне нужно чтобы когда игрок с ней сталкивается и начинает проигрываться анимация коллайдер у монетки отключался(чтобы избежать багов)

Проще говоря как через скрипт отключить коллайдер у объекта к которому привязан скрипт?

Как это сделать?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У компонентов есть булево свойство `enabled`.
Отключить коллайдер можно следующим образом:

```
coin.GetComponent<Collider>().enabled = false;
```

или, если это 2D игра:

```
coin.GetComponent<Collider2D>().enabled = false;
```

Comment: Спасибо помогло!